# Gitlab-Runner + Minio empty bucket

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner, minio

I have tried to configure my Gitlab-runner with a Minio bucket.
When i start the pipeline it says:

```
Creating cache master-env-16...
env: found 1647 matching files and directories     
Uploading cache.zip to https://minio.xxxxxx.com/data/test/project/54/master-env-16 
Created cache
```

But when i look into the bucket, it is still empty.
Has anyone the same problem?

Here the cache conf from my runner:

```
  [runners.cache]
    Type = "s3"
    Path = "test"
    Shared = true
    [runners.cache.s3]
         ServerAddress = "minio.xxxxxx.com"
         AccessKey = "xxxxxx"
         SecretKey = "xxxxxx"
         BucketName = "data"
         Insecure = false
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the solution.
but i tell you just in case:

Minio have two port:

- Console: 9090 (example from minio docs)
- API: 9000 (example from minio docs)

Check when minio start up, this log next message

```
minio    | Status:         1 Online, 0 Offline. 
minio    | API: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9000  http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9000 
minio    | Console: http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9090 http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9090
```

For GitLab runner you need to use the API port. You need be sure that URI refere at API and not at Console